# How to pass data with custom events using an event bus in Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using **Vue.js** 2.5.x.

In my toy project, I've implemented an event bus (similarly to what shown [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)).
The event bus is globally registered in Vue prototype as `$eventBus`.

Then I created a component that emits an event as follows

```
this.$eventBus.$emit('actionCompleted')
```

and another that registers to that event to execute its own function (`myMethod`), as shown below

```
export default {
  created: function () {
      this.$eventBus.$on('actionCompleted', this.myMethod)
  },
  methods: {
    myMethod () {
        console.log('myMethod called')
    }
  }
}
```

So far so good, all works as expected.

The question is: how can I pass an object to my custom event so that I can ship additional information to the listeners?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass your parameter as second argument

`this.$eventBus.$emit('actionCompleted', objectParams)`

```
export default {
  created: function () {
      this.$eventBus.$on('actionCompleted', this.myMethod)
  },
  methods: {
    myMethod (objectParams) {
        console.log('myMethod called', objectParams)
    }
  }
}
```

You can check [following tutorial](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860)

Answer (score 3):

You can create event like this way for single argument:

```
this.$eventBus.$emit('actionCompleted',args)
```

**You can pass multiples arguments by comma separate values.**

multiples arguments:

```
this.$eventBus.$emit('actionCompleted',args1, args2 ...)
```

after passing that argument you can get as follow [for single argument]:

```
export default {
  created: function () {
      this.$eventBus.$on('actionCompleted', this.myMethod)
  },
  methods: {
    myMethod (args) {
        console.log('myMethod called', args)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply emit an object through your event bus:

```
this.$eventBus.$emit('actionCompleted', this.yourObject)
```

And then catch it like this:

```
export default {
  created: function () {
      this.$eventBus.$on('actionCompleted', this.myMethod)
  },
  methods: {
    myMethod (objectParams) {
        console.log('myMethod called', objectParams)
    }
  }
}
```